# Role Provider couldn't be found in the System.web.security?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to inherit the abstract class RoleProvider. However, I am getting errors
saying that RoleProvider doesn't exist in the Web.Security namespace.
This is what I am following - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

This is my class -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace blogging.Infrastructure
{
    public class RoleProvider:  System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have a reference to System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your class name.

See this example :

```
    public class AccountRoleProvider:  System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
    {

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. He specified the namespace of the class he wants to inherit.